# Get Difference between a Value and the Prior Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which pulls data from different table and I have the result set in as following

**Current Result Set**

[image: Current Result Set]

Further to have these columns Reading1, 2 and 3 I would like to have Difference between a Reading and the Reading prior to that reading. I want my result set to look like this

**Desired Result Set**

[image: Result SET]

in this result set to Calculate `R1_Change1` I am taking Difference between

```
44 - 38 =  6
38 - 46 = -8
46 - 17 = 17
17 - 25 = -8
```

and so on.... Please Advise Thanks in advance.. I have added the code for test data please have a look and advise. The answers I have got so far are not giving desired results but not so far either.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
[Date] DateTime,
Reading1 int,
Reading2 int,
Reading3 int
)
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES ('2013-10-01 00:00:00.000',44,27,22),
('2013-09-17 00:00:00.000',38,55,54),
('2013-09-11 00:00:00.000',46,63,65),
('2013-09-03 00:00:00.000',17,96,23),
('2013-08-21 00:00:00.000',25,87,54),
('2013-08-11 00:00:00.000',63,25,25)
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM (/*Your query here*/) A
)
SELECT  X.[Date],
        X.Reading1,
        ISNULL(X.Reading1,0) - ISNULL(Y.Reading1,0) R1_Change1,
        X.Reading2,
        ISNULL(X.Reading2,0) - ISNULL(Y.Reading2,0) R2_Change2,
        X.Reading3,
        ISNULL(X.Reading3,0) - ISNULL(Y.Reading3,0) R3_Change3
FROM CTE X
LEFT JOIN CTE Y
    ON X.RN = Y.RN + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out and replying but Your Query is not far off but its showing wrong results. Could please Try it your self and see if you can tweak it a little bit more to get the right result. Your Query has ordered the results Ascending and then subtracting older values from new values. Whereas I want address New values from Older values. I have added Create Table and values to my Question please try it your self and advise thank you.

Comment: @MuhammedAli The change needed seems trivial enough, just change the join condition from `ON X.RN = Y.RN - 1` to `ON X.RN = Y.RN + 1`. Updated my answer

Comment: Cheers Lamak works like a charm Thanks for your quick replies pal, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
select
[Date],
[Reading1],
R1_Change = [Reading1] - (select top 1 [Reading1] from Readings b where b.[Date] < a.[Date] order by b.[Date] desc),
[Reading2],
R2_Change = [Reading2] - (select top 1 [Reading2] from Readings b where b.[Date] < a.[Date] order by b.[Date] desc),
[Reading3],
R3_Change = [Reading3] - (select top 1 [Reading3] from Readings b where b.[Date] < a.[Date] order by b.[Date] desc),
from
Readings a
```